# Function composition when function parameters in wrong order

Tags: haskell

I understand that in Haskell it's important to put the most 'variable' argument (aka the input object) last in a function definition, to make the function as composable as possible ([reference](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Parameter_order)). But if I'm using a library function that doesn't follow this rule, is there any alternative/workaround to function composition to increase readability?

I'll give a specific example - the [subRegex](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/regex-compat/latest/doc/html/Text-Regex.html#v%3asubRegex) function takes the input string as the first of two arguments, and so chaining two of these plus a `toUpper` to create a "slugify" function I have ended up with the below:

```
slugify :: FilePath -> FilePath
slugify old =
   let (dir, file) = splitFileName old
   in combine dir $ subRegex (mkRegex "[ _]") (subRegex (mkRegex "[^.a-z0-9_ ]+") (map toLower file) "") "-"
```

Is there a function-composition-style way of tidying this up given the order of the subRegex arguments?

Comment: I don't know how helpful it would be here, but the [pointfree](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointfree) tool is sometimes useful for these types of things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always provide a small helper to change the argument order into something more composable:

```
slugify :: FilePath -> FilePath
slugify old =
    let (dir, file) = splitFileName old
    in combine dir $ sub "[ _]" "-" $ sub "[^.a-z0-9_ ]+" "" $ map toLower file
  where
    sub regex replacement input = subRegex (mkRegex regex) input replacement
```

In simple cases, you can also use [`flip`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v:flip) or a lambda expression, but in this case I think a local definition is nicer. It also makes it easy to remove the duplication of the calls to `mkRegex`.

Comment: `sub = flip . subRegex . mkRegex`

Comment: Obviously the ideal solution[1] here is using type hackery for variadic [flip](https://github.com/isomorphism/typewriter/blob/master/Data/Typewriter/Variadic/Flip.hs) or [function composition](https://github.com/isomorphism/typewriter/blob/master/Data/Typewriter/Variadic/Compose.hs) *([1] -- N.B. not actually an ideal solution )*

Comment: Thanks @hammar, that looks great to me. I'm going to look into `flip` but yes I think your solution hits the spot for this one.